# What kind of search should be used

Tags: python, django, search

I'm working on a online store using Django, the question is simple, for a simple model named Product with "name" and "description" fields, should I try a full text search using PostgreSQL or a simple query using "icontains" field lookup?

Comment: Try both and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use full text search is to search a single term against a single column in the database.
example: `Product.objects.filter(description_text__search='lorem')`

Searching against a single field is great but rather limiting. To query against both fields, use a SearchVector

Same way you can use SearchQuery too.

Comment: Can I use search vectors with a database other than postgreSQL? that's my main problem, the project is not in production yet but I would like to know if I would have to migrate my database from MySQL.

Comment: I guess from the above comment, Better to search vectors using other than Postgres